# How can I parse the output of SQL stored procedure in node js?

Tags: json, node.js, stored-procedures, node-seriate

I'm calling a stored procedure using seriate to register users and the output JSON like this when the user is created and the first value {"":208} is the generated userId

`{"sets":{"sp_CreateNewUser":[[[{"":208}],[{"":1664}],[{"":1665}],[{"":1666}],[{"":1667}],[{"":1668}],[{"":1669}],[{"":1670}],[{"":1671}],[{"":210}],[{"":212}]],0]},"transaction":{}}`

and it looks like this when it fails

```
{"sets":{"sp_CreateNewUser":[[[{"":-1}]],0]},"transaction":{}}
```

How can I parse this output so to grab the userId and pass it to the next function or if the out put -1 to do another function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying all sort of parsing and looping methods with no luck,
not sure if its the best way to do, but I found I can grab it and assign 
variable this way

```
var id = user.sets.sp_CreateNewUser['0']['0']['0'][''];
```

after success i get `id = '208'` or `id = '-1'` on failure

Answer (score 0):

As your response is in json format you can use JSON.parse() function. or you can assign output json to array/variable and using for loop you can traverse through it and access it